# ntpd unable to create socket on en0

Tags: macos, error, server.app, logs, ntp

I have a mac mini running OS X Server (Mavericks, 10.9.1 - latest Server.app) and I keep getting these error messages in them system logs every few minutes. I am not sure if there is a real problem or not.

> Jan 22 08:20:54 myosxserver.com ntpd[???]: unable to create socket on
>   en0 (????) for ipv6here

Is there really something wrong? or can I disable ntpd from logging these?

Comment: did you change anything in the ntp.conf? Do you have ipv6 disabled on the ethernet interface?

Comment: no I have not, and I just checked and it seems to have the europe apple server as expected (?) in one line as: server time.euro.apple.com. I believe the ipv6 is enabled on the ethernet as it has an ipv6 address when I look in the network pref.

Comment: I take it ipv6here was the ipv6 address? did you replace something with (????)? What is the output of `sudo lsof -n -i UDP:123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I corrected this by using this in the terminal:

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.euro.apple.com
```

Comment: ntpdate is now deprecated. If /etc/ntp.config contains "time.euro.apple.com" then `sudo ntpd -q` does the same thing and is the recommended alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I had done that too, I guess this one must have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding the following line to /etc/ntp.conf

```
interface ignore ipv6
```

and then restarting ntpd